# Why does waiting once on multiple calls to HttpClient.GetStringAsync() take as long as waiting individually on each call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
using System.Net.Http;  
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Diagnostics;  

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ExceuteMultipleRequestsInParallel()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start(); 
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> ms = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
        Task<string> msdn = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        Task<string> blogs = client.GetStringAsync("http://blogs.msdn.com");
        await Task.WhenAll(ms, msdn, blogs);
        sw.Stop();
        var result = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ExcecuteMultipleRequests()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string ms = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
        string msdn = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        string blogs = await client.GetStringAsync("http://blogs.msdn.com");
        sw.Stop();
        var result = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    }
}
```

At first I only used one `HttpClient`. My expectation was that one `await Task.WhenAll(...)` would take about the time the longest task would take. My expectation was also that this would take measurably less than calling each of the three tasks with an await.

However, this didn't seem to be the case. Also I always had to comment one as otherwise the cache would distort things.

Then I used three `HttpClients` and surprisingly the method using three times await took less time then the one using `await Task.WhenAll(...)`. This seems strange.

Would someone please explain why I do not see the same improvement in elapsed time using `WhenAll()` in the first scenario (calling a single `HttpClient` three times) as I do in the second (calling three `HttpClient` instances once each)?

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task ExceuteMultipleRequestsInParallel()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient client3 = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> ms = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
        Task<string> msdn = client2.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        Task<string> blogs = client3.GetStringAsync("http://blogs.msdn.com");
        await Task.WhenAll(ms, msdn, blogs);
        sw.Stop();
        var result = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ExcecuteMultipleRequests()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient client3 = new HttpClient();
        string ms = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
        string msdn = await client2.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        string blogs = await client3.GetStringAsync("http://blogs.msdn.com");
        sw.Stop();
        var result = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What's your question...?

Comment: @Andi: Testing timings with the network - particularly against large sites that doubtless have server farm backends - introduces a *ton* of variables. You may not be measuring what you think you're measuring.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe sounds perfectly normal to me. I see no reason to expect a single `HttpClient` instance to process more than one HTTP operation at any given time.

So when you use a single `HttpClient` instance, if you call `GetStringAsync()` again before the first call has completed, the class has no choice but to simply queue the operation and not start that one until the previous one has completed. Likewise the third operation.

When you use three different instances, each is able to proceed independently and so all three requests can happen concurrently.

The fact that you wait on all three operations concurrently (i.e. call `WhenAll()`) cannot and does not change the order in which they are actually executed internally by `HttpClient`. That `HttpClient` is able to give you three different tasks to wait on doesn't change the fact that a single instance of itself is able to only process one at a time. And since the last operation cannot even start until all of the previously enqueued operations have completed, you get the same basic elapsed time as if you had simply waited for each operation to complete in turn before enqueuing the next one yourself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `HttpClient` is *supposed* to allow multiple concurrent requests from the same instance (actually concurrent, not just queued). The intended usage of `HttpClient` is as a singleton (or near-singleton), a repository of common settings (custom headers, etc).

Comment: @Stephen: interesting. I was unable to find any documentation that supports that idea (I looked before even answering the above). At the same time, I have no reason to doubt your assertion (other than the OP's observations seem to suggest otherwise). Do you have a official reference that supports the notion that not only can `HttpClient` accept concurrent requests (which it obviously can), it can _process_ those requests concurrently?

Comment: No official source. It just seems to be the general consensus.

Comment: Putting an update here with requested source [from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.0): "Although HttpClient implements the IDisposable interface, it's designed for reuse. Closed HttpClient instances leave sockets open in the TIME_WAIT state for a short period of time."